# Scroll up to in Vim term

Tags: vim

I have a terminal window in vim and need to see the output that is on a higher line than is shown. How do I "scroll" up to see that?

Command that I opened my terminal with:

```
:term bash
```

Comment: have you tried CTRL+Y or CTRL+E?

Comment: @mael' That works in the editor window but not the terminal window. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Might be a good question for https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>, it pauses the terminal, and you can navigate it like any buffer. Pressing <kbd>i</kbd> takes you back into the terminal as you were before.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `neovim`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to enter normal mode in a terminal.

The help (`:help terminal-input`) says the following:

> In this mode all keys except `<C-\><C-N>` are sent to the underlying program. Use `<C-\><C-N>` to return to normal-mode. `CTRL-\_CTRL-N`

ps. You might want to map this to a more sensible combination, like for example double escape:

```
tnoremap <Esc><Esc> <C-\><C-n>
```

Comment: Not using neovim but good to know